# Eclipse - Android app crashing

Tags: java, android, xml

I recently started learning how to develop apps using eclipse, i have made an app and a menu for it. Upon opening the app, i get the start up screen which is supposed to stay for 5 seconds and then move into the menu. After the start up screen the app crashes. I am developing 4.1.2. my log cat report is the following

```
05-08 13:46:21.170: V/MediaPlayer(16864): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0

05-08 13:46:21.170: V/MediaPlayer(16864): playback complete

05-08 13:46:21.170: V/MediaPlayer(16864): callback application

05-08 13:46:21.170: V/MediaPlayer(16864): back from callback

05-08 13:46:23.585: D/Instrumentation(16864): 
checkStartActivityResult  :Intent { act=com.example.first_app.MENU }

05-08 13:46:23.585: D/Instrumentation(16864): 
checkStartActivityResult  inent is instance of inent:

05-08 13:46:23.590: W/dalvikvm(16864): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f122a0)
05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1262

05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No 
Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.first_app.MENU }

05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864):    at 

android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1580)
05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864):    at 

android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864):    at 

android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864):    at 

android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864):    at 

android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864):    at 

android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864):    at 

com.example.first_app.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:28)

05-08 13:46:23.615: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(16864): release

05-08 13:46:23.615: V/MediaPlayer(16864): setListener

05-08 13:46:23.615: V/MediaPlayer(16864): disconnect

05-08 13:46:23.620: V/MediaPlayer(16864): destructor

05-08 13:46:23.620: V/MediaPlayer(16864): disconnect
```

my code is

```
package com.example.first_app;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = {"startingPoint", "example1", "example2", "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{                    
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.first_app." + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   
}
```

and i also have my manifest as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.first_app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".startingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.first_app" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"  android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="come.example.first_app.MENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: post your code so that any one can debug

Comment: You're calling an intent called com.example.first_app.MENU that doesn't exist.  Make sure that you named it properly, and that you added the activity to your manifest.  Beyond that, you'll need to post code.

Comment: Do you have an `intent filter` in your `manifest` for `Menu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:
`<action android:name="**come**.example.first_app.MENU" />`

You meant to type "com" not "come"

And just FYI: The way I found that was in the error log. The line:

```
05-08 13:46:23.590: E/AndroidRuntime(16864): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No
```

Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.first_app.MENU }

Shows me that in your app you were trying to create an activity called "com.example.first_app.MENU" but that activity was not part of your project. I expected your android manifest to not have that node at all. But I found it was there with a typo. Hope that helps you.